# IE Disappearing Bullet Bug in Floated DIV

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

There is a world of suggestions on forums about this but none have shown any sign of success for me yet.

I have a floated div which contains ULs styled to use a bullet image.  All compliant browsers show the image fine.  When I refresh the page in IE 6 the bullets frequently show up but disappear again when the page is scrolled. In IE 7 they just fail to show up.

Page is here:

http://hiv411.org/page.php?pID=13&n=Other_STDs

Relevant CSS:

```
#hiv101STDSidebar UL {
width:215px;
}

#hiv101STDSidebar LI {
position:relative;  /* added per some forum post, no effect*/
list-style-image:url(/images/layout/squareBulletBlue.gif);
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.  It would be a shame to have to re-write those ULs as tables!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by others, use a background image instead of a bullet image.

HTML

```
<div id="floated">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Item
            </li>
            <li>
                Item 2
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
div#floated {
    float: left;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    background: transparent url(squareBulletBlue.gif) no-repeat 0 2px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 1.2em;
}
```

Works in IE6 and 7 for me, if it doesn't then you've got other problems with your code :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Implemented and now I can die happy!  If you are ever in New Orleans I owe you a beer!

Answer (score 2):

Try styling the bullet with the background attribute.

```
selector li {
    background: transparent url(/images/layout/squareBulletBlue.gif) left center no-repeat;
    paddding-left: 25px; 
}
```

You might have to reset the `padding` and `margin` on your `ul` selector.

Comment: I tried that out.  Same results.  Intermittent display in IE6 and no display in IE7.

Thanks for the reply!

JG

Comment: This should work, you've got something else going on.  I'll make a post with some more code examples.

Answer (score 2):

This fixes it in ie6 & 7:

```
#hiv101STDSidebar ul {
  width: 215px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0; /* resetting margin */
  padding: 0 0 0 40px; /* using padding to position ul */
}
```

Haven't had time to properly investigate, but it seems to be the inherited left margin of the sidebar that's causing the problem. Using padding on the ul fixes the weird behaviour in ie6 and ie7 but it doesn't play nice with standard compliant browsers so you need to add this style with your conditional lte ie7 css.

Hope this helps.